# PHPMyAdmin - How to fix #1006 - Can't create database 'database_name' (errno: 13 “permission denied”) in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, permission-denied, ubuntu-20.04

In my **Ubuntu 20.04 (Desktop/Laptop not server)** OS based machine I recently install XAMPP (Version: 7.4.7).
Now when I try to create a database it shows #1006 - Can't create database 'database_name' (errno: 13 "permission denied").

I am not quite familiar with Ubuntu in recent times (last use Ubuntu 18.04), so I can't figure out in which file I need to do the configuration or in which directory I need to allow the permission so that the problem is fixed. Can anyone help me to fix the issue?

N.B: Will I need to install MySQL separately(although XAMPP is included), because **mysql** command is not working from terminal.

- Thanks

Comment: I believe an error 13 does indeed relate to file system permissions (rather than MySQL permissions). If you can connect to the command line client and run the `STATUS;` command it will show you the "datadir" which is the path on disk for the MySQL databases. How have you installed MySQL — you only mention XAMPP once; if you use the Ubuntu package manager, I believe the path is `/var/lib/mysql`, but XAMPP uses its own paths. Do not install more than one database server; at best you'll confuse things, at worst you could corrupt your databases.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create database, you do it with html view ? (using your browser like phpmyadmin) or direcly from XAMMP ?

I never use XAMPP sorry.

Did you try to install it separately ?

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Comment: XAMPP included everything like PHP, MySQL, Apache. Yes, it shows the expected HTML view of PHPMyAdmin, but when I try to create a database it shows the error.

Comment: mysql is running with which user ? Did you check that ?

Try : ls -l /var/lib/ 

I don't know where exactly where XAMPP mysql stores databases but this is an example.

If mysql dir is present in this location, check the directory owner